# Material Design Lite - Bottom Line in text field has a slight gap with colored line

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-design-lite

I am trying to get Material Design Lite text field to work and I have an issue where the bottom colored line has a slight 3-4 px gap between the gray starting line. Any MDL text Field example I plug into my page I get the same result, what can locally be triggering the issue? Also I am using react.js on the frontend.

I am on 1.2.1 of material design lite.

Here is an image:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input className="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"/>
        <label className="mdl-textfield__label" htmlFor="nameField">
            Your name
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a working example? fiddle or pen?

Comment: Any examples I use from: https://getmdl.io/components/#textfields-section I get the same gap when added to my code. But they render fine online.

Comment: As @PraneshRavi said, without seeing your implemented code, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Try implementing like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/4t662wdk/

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using componentHandler.upgradeDom() because the html is added dynamically. Issue is in both IE and Chrome. Putting bottom: 15px on mdl-textfield__label:after fix the issue (HACK).

Comment: I have verified that upgradeDom() is called when the page loads. I'm noticing a similar issue with my mdl spinner. It shows "Loading..." instead of the spinning animation, which also seems to be the same issue. Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

I did face the same issue with MDL when used with boostrap and turns out the boostrap css file adds a margin of 5px to its bottom for the Label elment which  creates a 5px gap.

[JSFiddle-Recreating the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/ilinkmat/90u6Lxc4/)

Code snippet from Bootstrap.css file

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Fix** would be reduce the margin-bottom of the label element to 0px.

[Fix- JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilinkmat/90u6Lxc4/2/)

```
.mdl-textfield__label{  
   margin-bottom:0px;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: MDL + Bootstrap, now this makes sense for me, Thanks