# MDL - Text field shows bottom line in middle

Tags: material-design, material-design-lite

The bottom line for text-field is shown a bit above.
No CSS used ...

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" id="phone">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="phone">Phone</label>
  <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Digits only</span>
</div>

<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">

    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="demo-input" />

    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="demo-input">UserName...</label>
  </div>
 </form>
```

[Take a look at what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLVsa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answer which i posted for the below stackoverflow thread.

[Material Design Lite - Bottom Line in text field has a slight gap with colored line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535700/material-design-lite-bottom-line-in-text-field-has-a-slight-gap-with-colored-l/40029403#40029403)